# How to read parentheses or brackets using CPLEX

Tags: constraints, cplex, lpsolve, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to read a .lp file using CPLEX, and it is giving me an error 1615, which is not being able to read "(" or even "[". I am not happy with it because what I have needs to be read must have parentheses in it. Here is what I have:

[num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5] * 1/12

First of all, I don't know how CPLEX would take in the multiplication sign. So, instead I have:

[num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5] 1/12

And, then it may not be able to read fractions or the division sign. I am not even sure how to write this, so that it reads it. I can't solve the problem unless CPLEX reads the file successfully.

Now, similarly I am also using LPsolve, and it also cannot read parentheses, fractions, multiplication sign, and a division sign. Both of these are currently useless for me. In LPsolve, I just have to copy and paste the content into the window, and run it.

If any of you have an alternate way to write the statement I have above or a way for either CPLEX or LPsolve to read it, then that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The following is not valid syntax for the LP file format:

> [num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5] 1/12

Square brackets ([]) are only allowed in quadratic expressions.  Instead, you could do something like this:

0.083333 num1 + 0.083333 num2 + 0.083333 num3 + 0.083333 num4
+ 0.083333 num5

(note that you may loose some precision doing that as 1/12 is not exactly representable as a floating point number).

See the documentation for CPLEX LP format [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/FileFormats/topics/LP.html).  Also, keep in mind that there can be different implementations of the LP file format depending on the vendor (i.e., what works for LPsolve may not work for CPLEX and visa versa).